# ¿Como puedo remplazar un carácter en una posición específica de mi String en Java?

Tags: java, string

Necesito obtener el complemento a uno de un numero dado en binario almacenado en una cadena de tal forma que todos los ceros sean cambiados por unos y viceversa.
El metodo queda de la siguiente manera:

```
public static void obtenerComplemento (String cadena) {
    for (int i = 0; i < cadena.length(); i++) {
        if (cadena.charAt(i) == '0') {
            cadena.chartAt(i) = '1';
        } else {
            cadena.charAt(i) = '0'
        }
    }
    System.out.println("El complemento a uno es: " + cadena);
}
```

Comment: Las cadenas en Java no se pueden modificar como en otros lenguajes.
Como indica [FrEqDe](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/22112/freqde), la unica forma es crear una Nueva cadena (string) y copiar todos los otros caracteres.
<br>Para ver toda la informacion de las cadenas en Java, mira la documentacion (en ingles) [Java docs Strings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String no puede ser cambiado en Java.

Necesitas crear un nuevo String con el caracter reemplazado.

```
String variable = "Texto de la variable";
char c = 'X';
String nueva_variable = variable.substring(0,4)+c+variable.substring(5);
```

Esto sería "Textx de la variable"

O puedes utilizar StringBuilder

```
StringBuilder variable = new StringBuilder("Texto"); variable.setCharAt(4, 'x');
```

El resultado en este caso sería "Textx"

En pocas palabras String es inmutable y StringBuilder mutable.

Tu código se vería de la siguiente manera:

```
public static void obtenerComplemento (StringBuilder cadena) {
    for (int i = 0; i < cadena.length(); i++) {
        if (cadena.charAt(i) == '0') {
            cadena.setCharAt(i,'1');
        } else {
            cadena.setCharAt(i,'0');
        }
    }
    System.out.println("El complemento a uno es: " + cadena);
}
```

Recuerda llamar el método con parámetro de tipo StringBuilder:

```
obtenerComplemento(new StringBuilder("Tu texto auquí"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Que yo sepa un String no tiene el método `charAtIndex`(). Puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
public static String obtenerComplemento (String cadena) {
String cadena_nueva="";
    for (int i = 0; i < cadena.length(); i++) {
        if (cadena.charAt(i) == '0') {
                    cadena_nueva+="1";
        } else {
            cadena_nueva+="0";
        }
    }
    System.out.println("El compleneto a uno es: " + cadena_nueva);
return cadena_nueva;
}
```

Comment: Resuelve el problema pero, no de la manera en que me lo piden. Se supone que es para hacer una implementación en Java de una maquina de Turing por lo cual debo modificar la cadena que reprecenta la cinta en dicha maquina y no cambiarla. De todas formas se agradece tu contribución

Answer (score 0):

He modificado tu codigo para que sea similar a tu codigo base pero retornando el String que deseas :

```
public static String obtenerComplemento (String cadena) 
{
    //creamos un objeto StringBuilder ya que para los casos en los cuales una cadena cambiara varias veces es mas optimo
    StringBuilder nuevaCadena = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < cadena.length(); i++) 
    {
        //añadimos los caracteres a la cadena , si el caracter actual es un 0 debemos ingresar un 1 utilizando un if ternario.
        nuevaCadena.append( cadena.charAt(i)=='0'?"1":"0" );

    }
    //imprimimos la cadena
    System.out.println("El complemento a uno es: " + cadena);
    //imprimimos el complemento
    System.out.println(nuevaCadena);
    //retornamos un nuevo String
    return nuevaCadena.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Un `String` en Java es inmutable. Para trabajar con y cambiar las caracteres, la manera más simple sería usar un arreglo de `char`:

```
char[] str = cadena.toCharArray();
// ahora como tenemos un arreglo podemos cambiar caracteres:
for (int i = 0; i<str.length; i++){
    str[i] = (str[i] == 48) ? (char) 49 : 48;
}
String resultado = new String(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

La clase `String` es inmutable. Esto significa que **no** puedes modificar un objeto de tipo `String`: cualquier operación que ofrece la API de la clase en realidad devuelve otro objeto `String` sin modificar la referencia original.

Una posible solución al problema es que conviertas el objeto `String` a un arreglo de `char`, manipules ese arreglo (que sí lo puedes hacer porque el arreglo contiene datos primitivos) y una vez termines de manipularlo, lo conviertas nuevamente a un `String`

```
public static String obtenerComplemento (String cadena) {
    char[] cadenaChars = cadena.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < cadenaChars.length; i++)
        if(cadenaChars == '0')
            cadenaChars[i] = '1';
        else 
            cadenaChars[i] = '0';
    return String.valueOf(cadenaChars);
}
```

El código anterior asume que `cadena` solo contiene caraćteres binarios.
El método `tocharArray()` retorna una representación de la cadena original como un arreglo de carácteres, por ejemplo, para la cadena "011100" devuelve un arreglo que contiene el carácter '0' en la primera posición, '1' en la segunda, etc. Luego, recorre todo el arreglo buscando los caracteres que son iguales a '0', si encuentra a uno convierte elcaracter en esa posición a '1', de lo contrario asume que es un '1' y convierte el caracter en esa posición a '0'. Al terminar, usa el método `valueOf()` de la clase `String` que acepta como argumento un arreglo de caracteres y retorna la representación en `String` de ese dato.

Es importante mencionar que tu método original no retorna nada (la firma es `void`). Lamentablemente no es posible hacer lo que planteas bajo ese supuesto* ya que asumes que el objeto original que recibes como parámetro puedes modificarlo, pero esto, como mencioné, es imposible en Java con un objeto de tipo `String`.